# Error: No such option yet I've clearly set the option up

Tags: python, python-click

I'm just starting out with a simple project and using the Click library and have hit a snag early on that I can't figure out. When I run this with the "--testmode" flag it shows as True however the subsequent function doesn't execute and I get an error that no such option is defined? What am I doing wrong here?

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--user', prompt=True)
@click.option('--password', prompt=True, hide_input=True, confirmation_prompt=False)
def authenticate(user, password):
    pass

@click.command()
@click.option('--age')
@click.option('--testmode', is_flag=True)
def main(age, testmode):
    print('Age: ', age)
    print('Testmode: ', testmode)

    if testmode:
        authenticate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Console output:

```
python .\dev.py --help
Usage: dev.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --age TEXT
  --testmode
  --help      Show this message and exit.


python .\dev.py --testmode
Age:  None
Testmode:  True
Usage: dev.py [OPTIONS]
Try 'dev.py --help' for help.

Error: no such option: --testmode
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    if testmode:
        authenticate()
```

You're calling `authenticate()` like a function, but you've defined it as another `click.command`. That means it's going to look at `sys.argv` for command line options, find `--testmode`, and compare that against the options you defined with `@click.option`.

The `authenticate` method doesn't have a `--testmode` option, hence the error you're seeing.

There are various ways to fix this. Does `authenticate` really need to be configured as a command? The way you've got your code set up right now there's no way to call it via the command line.

Comment: I see. Thank you for that explanation! No, I don't need authenticate to be setup as a command. I was thinking to use click to grab some additional input depending on the flags/options used for main, but I could just as easily do that from within the function I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Iarsks answer is what you're looking for, but to elaborate on that further, the Click documentation has some information on invoking other commands. So if you really wanted `authenticate` to be setup as a command, you have 2 options.

1. Abstract the logic from `authenticate` into a python method, and invoke that inside `authenticate` and the `if testmode` block.
2. Look into invoking one command from another. Click commands have access to a context, which is a way for click to hold state referring to the current command, and other commands. More information can be found [here](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/advanced/#invoking-other-commands).

For clarity, a click context `ctx` can invoke another command as such:
`ctx.invoke(authenticate, user=user_value, password=password_value)`.

If the current command that was invoke has the same options and parameters as the other one you'd like to invoke, click offers a shorthand for it:
`click.forward(authenticate)`, which will pass the same arguments to the `authenticate` command.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, but with a different cause.  Posting for others who may run into it.

I was running `myscript.py -?` and getting the message `error: no such option: -o`.  Very confusing, I entered one option (`-?`) which exists, but it complained about a different one (`-o`).  Checked my environment, imports, even thought optparse library may have been corrupted.

Turns out I (somehow, mistakenly) had a file named `-o` in current dir. So bash was turning `-?` into `-o` and passing it to my script.  SMH.  Always check your fileystem!